# pip installation issue getpip file

Tags: python, django, shell, package, pip

I am trying to install pip folowing this tut:

```
http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/#installing
```

i copy the code from getpip.py, save it and run it with python, but the shell just closes half a second later, i am stuck on this.

`The Simple Way

Since pip depends on setuptools, you’ll need to install that first. I’ve written a small (experimental) script to make this easier — just download getpip.py and run it in the Python interpreter. (On Mac OS or Linux, you may need to run it as ‘sudo python getpip.py’.) This will install (or upgrade) setuptools, then use easy_install to install pip.`

i am using windows and trying to install it globally!

Comment: did you install setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools ?  use the exe ... then just do `easy_install pip`

Comment: Maybe this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) can help you